# Can you use XHTML to do responsive site

Tags: html, xhtml, responsive-design

can you use XHTML 1.0 strict markup and do responsive site? I think media queries are more of CSS3 but is there any limits with it to with XHTML? Don't ask why I need to XHTML :/ It's because the this huge site is done with it and now this small campaign site needs to use it too. The whole  part (and the header too) comes from this old site.

Thx!

Comment: Responsive sites (through media queries) are part of CSS-- not HTML/XHTML. So yes, you can have an XHTML 1.0 site that is responsive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsive web design its only for HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572829/responsive-web-design-its-only-for-html5)

Answer (score 2):

**XHTML5** = HTML5 + XML Parser.

My site is http://www.jabcreations.com/ and I use PHP to determine through client headers if their browser supports XHTML which is only really XHTML if it's served as application/xhtml+xml.

I have encountered no limits with XHTML and in fact it's far better than regular HTML. Because coding is stricter (again if you actually serve the media type/mime correctly along with the correct doctype) it truly helps produce much cleaner leaner code. At first yes it's a bit more difficult however stricter code doesn't mean less dynamic code. Stricter code is easier to work with because you will have a much better understanding of what to expect. With text/html all sorts of things can be staring you in the face and you wouldn't even know it. In example a person on forums I used to frequent had literally spent days trying to figure out why CSS was breaking in just Safari, as it turns out they were missing a quote. Had they served their content as XHTML the page would have broken in their local testing (because you DO test local before committing code to live sites like say every single email provider?) and it would have taken seconds to fix.

I've coded my own blog, CMS, control panel, forums, private messaging, statistics and much more all served this way. Stricter higher standards can and does lead to better code and has allowed me to do a lot more than if I didn't hold standards so high.

...and pretty much every argument against XHTML is null and void. You can serve XHTML 1.0 Strict doctype (instead of XHTML 1.1) for non-XHTML browsers. You can't nor shouldn't use document.write (not should you make script elements children of the body element).

Additionally my site uses CSS3 media queries so if you're talking about responsive to mobile browsers yes, you can do that in combination too. Simply resize your browser horizontally on my blog and watch as the layout adapts with the decreasing rendering area essentially emulating smaller screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

(X)HTML is not the part the actually creates the responsive elements. Its only job is the structure of a website. CSS, or to be specific CSS3, is the part that makes a website responsive.

Comment: You mean that the responsive element of a website is *not the job* of HTML or XHTML. As Andrew M mentions in his comment under the question, you can use XHTML for a responsive site.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Bad choice of words on my part.

Answer (score 1):

While responsive design is still *mostly* talked about in the context of CSS3, as several answers correctly pointed out, it's not really quite so simple now as it was in 2012. Responsive features have come to the HTML5 side of the equation as well, and you lose access to at least one important one by restricting yourself to XHTML: <img srcset>.

So, considering this question today I would answer no: You can't do a **fully** responsive site in XHTML, not to the same level that HTML5 makes possible.